# Which IPC mechanisms require a GUI application ? Windows platform

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc

Which IPC mechanisms require a GUI application ? Windows platform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx#base.using_data_copy_for_ipc

The following IPC mechanisms are supported by Windows:

Clipboard

COM

Data Copy

DDE

File Mapping

Mailslots

Pipes

RPC

Windows Sockets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'GUI application' - none of these technically require to have a GUI present; though some may require use of hidden HWNDs/windows behind the scenes which in turn may require a thread to run a message loop. (Note that in Windows, a console application can use any win32 API - so the only real distinction between a console app and a win32 app is whether the process gets allocated a console automatically when it starts; otherwise both apps can use the same API set and either create visible windows or not.)

DDE does, from what I remember, rely on messages between windows - so would require a message loop etc. But those windows don't need to be visible, so from a user's point of view, doesn't need to be a GUI application.

COM supports both applications that are message-loop based, and those that are more unix- or server- style multithreaded.

Data Copy - if this is WM_COPYDATA you're referring to, then it does require the recipient to have a HWND (which could be invisible), but not the sender.

The clipboard is typically used with a window, but doesn't require one (OpenClipboard can take a NULL hwnd.)

File Mapping, Mailslots, RPC and Windows Sockets don't require message loops.